Azure Notification Hub (1.1.0) Java 8 Compatibility
I have been trying to use the latest sdk of Azure Notification hub. (1.1.0) in my legacy Spring project(4.1.3) running in Jboss 7.0 EPA to be able to register the device using FCMV1 template(as this is the only version that supports FCMV1 registration). However, when I try to createRegistrationId or upsert the Registration using the sdk(through notificationHubClient) I get following exception. The request goes on infinite loop without executing this. Has anyone faced this before? Please provide any suggestions that you have tried to resolve this issue.
public String[] registerAndroidAppToNotificationHub(String deviceId, String notificationHubName,
        String pushNotificationDeviceToken) {

    String[] regIds = "";
    
    try {

        NotificationHub notificationHubClient = new NotificationHub(
                "notHubConnString", notificationHubName);
        
        int i = 0;
        for (NotificationHubRegistrationTemplate androidTemplate : androidNotificationHubRegistrationTemplates) {
            
            String regId = notificationHubClient.createRegistrationId(); //Fails here
            
            Registration reg = new FcmV1TemplateRegistration(regId, pushNotificationDeviceToken,
                    androidTemplate.getTemplate());
            
            Registration registrationResult = notificationHubClient.upsertRegistration(reg);

            regId = registrationResult.getRegistrationId();
             regId[i++] = regId;
        
        }
    } catch (NotificationHubsException e) {
        log.info("Error: " + e);
    }
    

    return regIds;
}

Here is the exception message :
09:42:48,486 ERROR [stderr] (httpclient-dispatch-1) Exception in thread "httpclient- 
dispatch-1" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
javax.net.ssl.SSLParameters.setApplicationProtocols([Ljava/lang/String;)V
09:42:48,488 ERROR [stderr] (httpclient-dispatch-1) at  
org.apache.hc.client5.http.ssl.DefaultClientTlsStrategy.applyParameters 
 (DefaultClientTlsStrategy.java:108)
 09:42:48,488 ERROR [stderr] (httpclient-dispatch-1) at 
 org.apache.hc.client5.http.ssl.AbstractClientTlsStrategy.
lambda$upgrade$0(AbstractClientTlsStrategy.java:138)
09:42:48,488 ERROR [stderr] (httpclient-dispatch-1) at 
org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.initialize(SSLIOSession.java:293)
09:42:48,488 ERROR [stderr] (httpclient-dispatch-1) at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.beginHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:268)
09:42:48,489 ERROR [stderr] (httpclient-dispatch-1) at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.InternalDataChannel.startTls(InternalDataChannel.java:258)
09:42:48,489 ERROR [stderr] (httpclient-dispatch-1) at org.apache.hc.client5.http.ssl.AbstractClientTlsStrategy.upgrade(AbstractClientTlsStrategy.java:111)
09:42:48,489 ERROR [stderr] (httpclient-dispatch-1) at org.apache.hc.client5.http.ssl.DefaultClientTlsStrategy.upgrade(DefaultClientTlsStrategy.java:48)
09:42:48,489 ERROR [stderr] (httpclient-dispatch-1) at org.apache.hc.core5.http2.nio.pool.H2ConnPool$1.completed(H2ConnPool.java:117)
09:42:48,490 ERROR [stderr] (httpclient-dispatch-1) at org.apache.hc.core5.http2.nio.pool.H2ConnPool$1.completed(H2ConnPool.java:110)
09:42:48,490 ERROR [stderr] (httpclient-dispatch-1) at org.apache.hc.core5.concurrent.BasicFuture.completed(BasicFuture.java:123)
09:42:48,490 ERROR [stderr] (httpclient-dispatch-1) at org.apache.hc.core5.concurrent.ComplexFuture.completed(ComplexFuture.java:72)
09:42:48,490 ERROR [stderr] (httpclient-dispatch-1) at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.nio.MultihomeIOSessionRequester$2$1.completed(MultihomeIOSessionRequester.java:150)
09:42:48,490 ERROR [stderr] (httpclient-dispatch-1) at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.nio.MultihomeIOSessionRequester$2$1.completed(MultihomeIOSessionRequester.java:142)
09:42:48,490 ERROR [stderr] (httpclient-dispatch-1) at org.apache.hc.core5.concurrent.BasicFuture.completed(BasicFuture.java:123)
09:42:48,491 ERROR [stderr] (httpclient-dispatch-1) at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.IOSessionRequest.completed(IOSessionRequest.java:73)
09:42:48,491 ERROR [stderr] (httpclient-dispatch-1) at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.InternalConnectChannel.onIOEvent(InternalConnectChannel.java:75)
09:42:48,491 ERROR [stderr] (httpclient-dispatch-1) at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.InternalChannel.handleIOEvent(InternalChannel.java:51)
09:42:48,492 ERROR [stderr] (httpclient-dispatch-1) at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.SingleCoreIOReactor.processEvents(SingleCoreIOReactor.java:178)
09:42:48,492 ERROR [stderr] (httpclient-dispatch-1) at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.SingleCoreIOReactor.doExecute(SingleCoreIOReactor.java:127)
09:42:48,494 ERROR [stderr] (httpclient-dispatch-1) at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.AbstractSingleCoreIOReactor.execute(AbstractSingleCoreIOReactor.java:86)
09:42:48,494 ERROR [stderr] (httpclient-dispatch-1) at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.IOReactorWorker.run(IOReactorWorker.java:44)


Try downgrading the Apache HTTP client library to a Java 8-compatible version, as the current SDK uses methods only available in Java 9+. Alternatively, consider implementing a custom client for FCMv1 registration with Java 8-compatible libraries.

@user6090970, The above error usually arises from an incompatible javax.net.ssl API version. This method, setApplicationProtocols, was introduced in Java 9.

If upgrading the server’s Java version is an option, this would directly solve the issue by making newer SSL/TLS features available. However, this could lead to additional testing and deployment overhead.

The NoSuchMethodError: javax.net.ssl.SSLParameters.setApplicationProtocols([Ljava/lang/String;)V error usually arises from an incompatible javax.net.ssl API version. This method, setApplicationProtocols, was introduced in Java 9, Suggesting that the Azure Notification Hub SDK (or one of its dependencies) is using newer SSL/TLS features that aren’t available in the JBoss 7.0 EPA environment if it’s running on Java 8 or earlier.

You can keep the existing Java version (Java 8) and JBoss 7.0 EPA without having to worry about upgrading them, which is important for legacy systems.

By downgrading the HTTP client to 4.x (which is fully compatible with Java 8), avoid issues related to SSL/TLS methods that are unavailable in the current Java version.


Update pom.xml to add Apache HTTP Client 4.x (compatible with Java 8) and exclude Apache HTTP Client 5.x (which requires Java 9 features).
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.13</version> <!-- Compatible with Java 8 -->
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-notificationhubs</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

After making above changes, tested the registration and notification functionality. resolved all the SSL-related errors and infinite loop and able to register devices with FCMv1.

